# Ruby routes URI regex

Tags: regex, ruby, routes, roda

I have blog web application on [Roda](http://roda.jeremyevans.net) where links have the following URL format: `example.com/posts/<id>/<slug>`.

For example `example.com/posts/1/example-blog-post`.

What I want to achieve is to redirect user to `example.com/posts/1/example-blog-post` in case he either visits:

1. example.com/posts/1 or
2. example.com/posts/1/ (note last backslash)

That's what I got in routes so far:

```
r.on /posts\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)/ do |id, slug|
  @post = Post[id]

  if URI::encode(@post[:slug]) == slug
    view("blogpage")
  else
    r.redirect "/posts/#{id}/#{@post[:slug]}"
  end
end
```

With this code:

1. example.com/posts/1 - **FAILS**
2. example.com/posts/1/ - **OK**

Can I satisfy both conditions?

Comment: Did you try making the last part optional? `posts\/([0-9]+)(?:\/(.*))?`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Thefourthbird please post an answer so we can mark this as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the forward slash followed by the second capturing group in an optional non capturing group:

```
posts\/([0-9]+)(?:\/(.*))?
```

**Explanation**

- `posts\/` Match `posts/`
- `([0-9]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/(.*)` Match `/` and capture in group 2 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/UJPcNtLFmD7fsU)